# Pandas to JSON file formatting issue, adding \ to strings

Tags: python, json, pandas, string, file-format

I am using the [pandas.DataFrame.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) to convert a data frame to JSON data.

```
data = df.to_json(orient="records")
print(data)
```

This works fine and the output when printing is as expected in the console.

```
[{"n":"f89be390-5706-4ef5-a110-23f1657f4aec:voltage","bt":1610040655,"u":"V","v":237.3},
{"n":"f89be390-5706-4ef5-a110-23f1657f4aec:power","bt":1610040836,"u":"W","v":512.3},
{"n":"f89be390-5706-4ef5-a110-23f1657f4aec:voltage","bt":1610040840,"u":"V","v":238.4}]
```

The problem comes when uploading it to an external API which converts it to a file format or writing it to a file locally. The output has added `\` to the beginning and ends of strings.

```
def dataToFile(processedData):
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(processedData,outfile)
```

The result is shown in the clip below

```
[{\"n\":\"f1097ac5-0ee4-48a4-8af5-bf2b58f3268c:power\",\"bt\":1610024746,\"u\":\"W\",\"v\":40.3},
{\"n\":\"f1097ac5-0ee4-48a4-8af5-bf2b58f3268c:voltage\",\"bt\":1610024751,\"u\":\"V\",\"v\":238.5},
{\"n\":\"f1097ac5-0ee4-48a4-8af5-bf2b58f3268c:power\",\"bt\":1610024764,\"u\":\"W\",\"v\":39.7}]
```

Is there any formatting specifically I should be including/excluding when converting the data to a file format?

Comment: It looks `processedData` is a string, not JSON object. Can you print `repr(processedData)` before you dump it. i.e. if it is already JSON string, you don't need to dump it.

Comment: `df.to_json()` returns a string, not dictionary, so you don't need to `json.dump()` it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data` variable is a string of json data and not an actual dictionary. You can do a few things:

1. Use `DataFrame.to_json()` to write the file, the first argument of `to_json()` is the file path:

```py
df.to_json('./data.json', orient='records')
```

2. Write the json string directly as text:

```py
def write_text(text: str, path: str):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(text)

data = df.to_json(orient="records")

write_text(data, './data.json')
```

3. If you want to play around with the dictionary data:

```py
def write_json(data, path, indent=4):
    with open(path, 'w') as file: 
        json.dump(data, file, indent=indent)

df_data = df.to_dict(orient='records')

# ...some operations here...

write_json(df_data, './data.json')
```

Comment: Yes this solved my problem, I did use slight variation using the ``` json.loads() ``` to play around with the dictionary as I don't always need the file, thank you!